# Logging User actions on Android

Tags: android, debugging, testing, logging

Is there a way to log a user's activity on an app. Basically, information like widget clicks, text inputs, swipes etc. I want these logs for my test case creation.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using Google Firebase in your Android projects for this.

[Get started here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) on Firebase for Android.

In code, you can do crash reporting on exceptions as easy as:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    FirebaseCrash.report(e);
}
```

And for general analytics, you can do something like this:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
    .logEvent("Something happened", someBundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use  [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) or [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/).

Firebase has multiple useful services. i like using it.

Comment: Does it provide the widget info of the application as well ? I basically want to log user behaviour on a specific application and what actions are performed on what components of the activity/ app/.

Comment: It provides infos like the version of Android used by the user, the device model and other useful infos..